# Why is substring-before() not working for me in XSLT?

Tags: xml, string, xslt, xslt-1.0

I was trying to extract the part of the filename in XSLT using some string functions and cannot understand why it does not work.

Here is the sample of XSLT I ran:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" 
    xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:variable name="A" >some.filename.test.CCYYMMDD.xml</xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="fileDateSplitChar" select="'.'"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>split char : </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="str:split($A,$fileDateSplitChar)[last()]"/>
    <xsl:text>split nodeset : </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="str:split($A,$fileDateSplitChar)"/>
    <xsl:text>substring-before : </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(str:split($A,$fileDateSplitChar)[last()],
                                                                           'xml')"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What I was trying to achieve is to extract the part of the filename, CCYYMMDD. When I ran it, the first message displays the split char properly; the second message returns the value 'some'; but the result of the third message is blank.

I'm using XSLT 1.0.

Comment: Improved title to better match question.   Formatted sample XML to improve readability.  Fixed capitalizations.   Made tagging reflect XSLT 1.0 specification in question.  Eliminate generic help/appreciation message per conventions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but the result of the third message is blank.

The result is blank, because:

```
str:split($A,$fileDateSplitChar)[last()]
```

returns "xml", and:

```
substring-before('xml, 'xml')"
```

returns an empty string.

> What I was trying to achieve is to extract the part of the file
>   CCYYMMDD.

I am assuming you don't know the ordinal position of this part, only that it's the one before the last - and therefore it can be extracted using:

```
str:split($A,$fileDateSplitChar)[last() - 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The EXSLT str:split function returns a node-set (because that's about the only data structure available in XSLT 1.0). `<xsl:value-of>`, when applied to a node-set, displays the string value of the first node, and ignores all the other nodes. Similarly, substring-before() when applied to a node-set processes the first node in the set, and ignores the remainder.

Are you really not able to move forward to XSLT 2.0?

Comment: Humans are like any other force of nature in that they will always follow the path of least resistance. XSLT 2.0 isn't supported in the .NET framework natively, or any major browser. Until it is, it's still a lot less effort to find an XSLT 1.0 solution rather than figuring out how to install and use a third party library. It may not even take much effort, but the perception is what's relevant. Sad, but true.

Comment: I think that's particularly true of humans who live their lives in the Microsoft ecosystem. Fortunately they're in a minority.